# NativeScript all debug builds worked and release builds crashed

Tags: vue.js, build, nativescript, release, nativescript-vue

NativeScript Application Crashes on start when in release build, but works well when in debug build 
any insight will be really helpful

[this is logical screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POk4T.png)

Comment: Any error messages (e.g. Android's `logcat`) and platform information (Android / iOS?) will be really helpful

Comment: I have added the logical screen shot

Comment: logcat screenshot has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot --bundle in build commandline